# Ошибка c++ -1073741819?

Tags: c++

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <iostream> 
#include <curl/curl.h> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std;
using namespace std::string_literals;
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    FILE* fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\GLEBHAS\\Desktop\\socks5.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Не удаёться открыть прокси файл." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    // Создаем экземпляр библиотеки curl 
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl == NULL) {
        curl_global_cleanup();
        std::cerr << "Ошибка инцилизации curl" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    char proxy[20];
    int proxy_length = 0;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", proxy + proxy_length) != EOF) {
        proxy_length += strlen(proxy + proxy_length);
    }
    proxy[proxy_length] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);

    std::string url = "https://www.twitch.tv/saunaragleb";
    std::string proxy_url = "socks5://"s + proxy;

    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, proxy_url.c_str());
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Option setting failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        return 1;
    }

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Perform failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

C:\Users\GLEBHAS\Desktop\c++\Scripts\x64\Debug\Scripts.exe (процесс 12756) завершил работу с кодом -1073741819.
Нажмите любую клавишу, чтобы закрыть это окно:

Comment: По закрытии окна обычно вам говорят причину в отладчике. Потом, неизвестно, что у вас в файле socks5.txt Может, у вас там больше 19 символов? :)